# Isotope insert method

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Can you help me please with odd isotope bug. When I init it, I use filter for limit results:

```
$grid.isotope({
    filter: '*:nth-child(-n+' + grid_items + ')'
});
```

So I see only 2 items (grid_items = 2).
But when I remove all elements and then insert new ones

```
$.each(items, function(index, val) {
    thtml += val;
});
$grid.isotope('insert', $(thtml))
```

All elements are hidden. If I don't use filter - all ok.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the layout after insert? E.g: `$grid.isotope('layout');`

Comment: Yep, no luck...

Comment: You might want to reset the filter: `$grid.isotope({ filter: '*' });`

Comment: Yep, in this case all right. But I want to filter items after insert.